# unable to connect to room using react-native-twilio-video-webrtc

Tags: twilio, react-native

I have generated an access token and create a room but as soon as I click on connect to join the room it shows an error like **TypeError: expected dynamic type `double`, but had type `string`**.
when I debug, found that calling

```
UIManager.dispatchViewManagerCommand(
  findNodeHandle(this.refs.videoView),
    event,
    args
  )
```

gives such error. I'm wondering where I'm wrong.

Comment: Are you finding that `event` or `args` is a `string` instead of a `double` in that call?

Comment: yeah, exactly the same situation

Comment: So where are you getting `event` or `args` from?

Comment: I've made a new project from scratch to test video calling, I'm able to implement it successfully. But for the project in which I want to add this video calling feature shows error for the same code. :(

Comment: So there must be something different between the way you call it in your example project and this one. Can you share more of your code to give a bit more context? Or compare your projects and try to figure what has gone wrong between them?

Comment: I'm sure that there is no difference, calling the test code and the main code snippet, I'm expecting there are some dependency problem but unable to figure it out. :(

Comment: Have you got a different version of Twilio Video in the new project to the original one? There must be something else different and I don't think I or anyone else can help with the detail you've given so far.